# Request for advice - Validation of settlement permit during absence from Germany

Tags: germany, immigration, resident-permit

I have a Niederlassungserlaubnis. I am planning to move to my home country for self employment and pursue an external part-time PhD from a German university (will visit Germany once a year for progress review and discussion). In case my self employment attempt fails, I would like to come back to Germany to finish my PhD as a full-time researcher at the university and then find a job.

Do you think the Ausländerbehörde will agree to keep my Niederlassungserlaubnis valid in my case? Will it help my case if I have a Dauraufenthalt EU since it allows 24 months of absence for prior Blue card holders?

Answer (score 1):

you mentioned the correct details. You can leave Germany and EU for up to 12 months and your "Niederlassungserlabunis" will be valid. If you had a Blue Card EU beforehand than you can leave Germany & EU for up to 24 month without loosing your permanent residency. Some info is provided by Berlins immigration office: [Permanent residence titles: EU long-term residence permit](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/aufenthalt/unbefristete-aufenthaltstitel/artikel.599387.en.php#DA-EU)
But keep in mind to come back before the 12/24 month expires. You dont get a chance to prolong the stay outside and will loose your permit.

New information on September 3rd: Following the law (§ 51 AufenthG) the residence permit expires if the foreigner leaves the country for a reason which is not temporary in nature. Might suit to your plans, as open a business isn`t temporary in that sense. So I would strongly recommend to disuss your plans with the responsible immigration office beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mentioned Niederlassungserlabunis in your message but I think you meant Daueraufenthalt-EU. Is that correct?

Comment: I mentioned Niederlassungserlaubnis as you were talking about this kind of residence type.

Comment: _Niederlassungserlaubnis_ (_NE_, lit. settlement permit) is just the _legal_ term for an _indefinite_ permit to stay, § 9 Ⅰ 1 [AufenthG](http://Bundesrecht.Juris.de/englisch_aufenthg). There is no expiration date. This is contrast to an _Aufenthaltserlaubnis_ (_AE_, lit. presence permit), a permit to stay for a _finite_ period, § 7 Ⅰ 1 AufenthG. An _Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt – EU_ is not associated with an expiration date so it is a _Niederlassungserlaubnis_, too. In general all regulations applicable to an _NE_ are also apply to an _Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt – EU_, § 9 Ⅰ 3 AufenthG.